# How to reload previous page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website in **ASP VB.NET** and there's a page that goes back to the previous one when clicked, we did this with JavaScript:

```
window.history.back();
```

But this gets you to the previous page on the state it had when going to the current page, we need it to reload, how can you do this?

Comment: You need to refresh the page. Have a look at this http://tinyurl.com/Jez-D007

Comment: How about window.location.href = "your_desired_url"; instead of window.history.back();

Comment: Because there are two different pages that link to the one in question, and I can't know which one called it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use `window.history` to achieve your desired behaviour because this is not how it works. `window.history` preserves the *session history* of the pages visited (as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) - it essentially mimics your browsers back/forward buttons.

As stated in the document:

> There is no way to clear the session history or to disable the back/forward navigation from unprivileged code. The closest available solution is the `location.replace()` method, which replaces the current item of the session history with the provided URL.

So your best bet to make this work would be to use `location.replace()`. You can get the previous URL of where you came from using `document.referrer`.

```
location.replace(document.referrer);
```